# Ubuntu 17.04 Nvidia 740m and Blender 2.7/2.8 (no GPU) CUDA issues

Tags: nvidia, cuda, gpu, blender

I have laptop with spec as provided in title with i7 processor and Intel Graphics, 
installed nvidia driver 384.59, Intel graphics driver with 
[Intel Graphics Update Tool](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-update-tool-linux-os-v2.0.5), with and without installed nvidia Cuda toolkit

installed Blender 2.28 from Blender PPA and Blender 2.8 from blender.org

Both versions can't see GPU available even I start blender as root with sudo ./blender

I also have no available options in nvidia settings (nvidia X server) which are just empty after nvidia driver installation - it looks like there's no any xorg or nvidia configuration or config files in the system

I installed corresponding nvidia-modprobe 384.59 but after reboot I couldn't login via lightdm, so had to remove this nvidia-modprobe (in ubuntu perositories/ppa there's only one old version of nvidia-modprobe)

How can I enable GPU in Blender in Ubuntu??? My nvidia 740m is correct as I have it working under same version of blender in Windows 10

I run out of ideas...

Comment: How did you installed the Nvidia drivers?

Comment: Look in Xorg.0.log Do you have an xorg.conf? it needs a device section with `driver nvidia`

Comment: MichaelBay: drivers installed via package manager from Ubuntu repository and then from added PPA graphics drivers, same with Intel drivers | 
sambler: that's something I don't get as I don't have created xorg.conf file on my system - several times checked for this when reinstalled drivers but with same effect after -> in "nvidia X server settings" have just standard window but with no configurations to edit provided